# How to install foo2zjs.tar.gz when website doesn't work

Tags: printing

Since http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/ is down for some time now, are there any alternatives for download of foo2zjs.tar.gz?

Comment: Try here: https://github.com/koenkooi/foo2zjs

Comment: or here: https://linux.softpedia.com/get/Printing/foo2zjs-8802.shtml

Comment: linux.softpedia.com redirects download to http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo2zjs.tar.gz` contains a source code that can be get from git repository (https://github.com/koenkooi/foo2zjs) as well.

Instructions that use this archive usually state to download this archive, extract it and then `make` from it, something like this:

```sh
wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
tar zxf foo2zjs.tar.gz
cd foo2zjs
make
```

By using GitHub repository as a source, just run following:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/koenkooi/foo2zjs.git
cd foo2zjs
make
```

Also, since source code from github already contains all firmware images, there is **no** need to run

```sh
./getweb 1018 # or some other printer
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a [deb-package from official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/foo2zjs), install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-foo2zjs
```